# Javascript OpenID Selector for mobile?

Tags: openid, mobile-website, openid4java

I've previously integrated Open Id authentication into my web app using [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) and [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/).  Now I'm working on a UI optimized for mobile web apps.

Can recommend something similar to openid-selector but geared towards mobile UI?

To be clear, the existing solution works in the mobile browser, however it isn't optimized for the mobile UI.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Been looking for a solution for this today, i need to make the images bigger so that they display properly on the Iphone. Did you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: i did not find a solution.  please let me know if you do.